# Mercurial hg mv doesn't move all files

Tags: mercurial, mv

Probably an easy one but I haven't dug up anything with the usual search queries so I thought I'd ask here. Basically I'm trying to rearrange my repo; for example:

```
mkdir test
hg mv DirectoryOfStuff test/
```

Mercurial moves *most* of the contents but it leaves some directories an files behind. So far I haven't seen any pattern to what it moves and what it doesn't.

Is there an obvious rule or command that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`hg mv` moves tracked files, not ignored or unknown ones.

To move everything and still record tracked files as a moved, use a regular (non-hg) move command and then `hg addremove -s 100`. The addremove command retrofits your file operations as add/remove/rename/move.

Use less than 100 to allow changes in file content & names.

Comment: @Macke all the files are in the repo. None are ignored and none are unknown (i.e. not tracked). This is why I don't understand why it doesn't work...

Comment: @PeterM: Weird. Are you running on Windows? If so, casing might be a problem? Make sure no files are opened by another program. Also, does it help to update hg to the latest version?

Comment: @Macke I'm actually on a Mac but my version is a bit out of date. I'm currently using 1.8.1. I'm upgrading it now to 1.8.3 but I don't think it will make much difference...

Comment: @Macke looks like you were right - something in my .hginore was masking it - only now I have the irony that if I remove the ignore it copies more stuff - but not all of it. Curse the make for creating a .DS_Store file in every directory...

Comment: @Macke Will I lose the file history with addremove though?

Comment: @PeterM: History is handled just as with move, i.e. not preserved inside the file, but the fact that it was copied is stored so most UI's are able to follow that copy. That just how Mercurial is designed at the moment. IMO, it's not optimal _at all_, but hopefully it'll improve in the future.